# Should the outlier detection be done only on the training set?

Tags: outliers

I have a dataset *D* which I will later divide into training and test sets. If I want to detect outliers, what would be the correct procedure?

1. Detect outlier in the dataset D and then divide it into training and testing.
2. Or first divide into training and test set and perform the outlier detection only in the training set. In this case, How do I check if the test set has outliers? Should I just report the performance in the test set regardless of the outlier presence?
   When I run the code

```py
estimators = []
estimators.append(('scaler',MinMaxScaler()))
estimators.append(('m', RandomForestClassifier()))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=1, random_state=1)

scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv, n_jobs=
print('Mean ROC AUC: %.3f' % np.mean(scores))
print('Std ROC AUC: %.3f' % np.std(scores))
print('Max ROC AUC: %.3f' % np.max(scores))
print('Min ROC AUC: %.3f' % np.min(scores))
```

The answer is :

```py
Mean ROC AUC: 0.568
Std ROC AUC: 0.075
Max ROC AUC: 0.675
Min ROC AUC: 0.419
```

Therefore I suspect that there are outliers in the dataset that could explain the difference in performance.

Comment: What do you plan to do when you identify an outlier, modify your data to better fit the model rather than modify the model to better fit your data?

Comment: Really depends on what the purpose of outlier detection is, and also what you will do when using the model in practice. E.g. if you detect outliers that are clearly obvious data entry errors, then it may be okay to have a production system that just refuses to give an output for such outliers (in that case it might - assuming this happens randomly and not due to some other characteristics of the records, sort of a garbled-at-random assumption similar to missing at random - be okay to just delete such cases in training and test, in most other cases not).

Comment: Dave, I edited the post. I run a cross-validation, and I found a big difference in the performance (high std). So I suspect that there area outliers in the dataset